# How to structure project for testing in dune

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I've created an OCaml project using dune with the intent of [running through these exercises](https://ocaml.org/problems):

```
dune init project ocaml_exercises
```

I've then created two lib files, `last.ml` and `last_two.ml` which contain one function a piece:

```ml
let rec last list =
  match list with
  | [] -> None
  | [x] -> Some x
  | _ :: tail -> last tail
```

```ml
let rec last_two list =
    match list with
    | [] -> None
    | [_] -> None
    | [x; y] -> Some (x, y)
    | _ :: tail -> last_two tail
```

Now, I'd like to test these, and I notice that dune has auto-created me a tests folder, great! So I've created two files in my test project: `last_tests.ml` and `last_two_tests.ml`. Resulting in a project dir that looks like this:

```
.
├ (build folder)
├── bin
│  ├── dune
│  └── main.ml
├── dune-project
├── lib
│  ├── dune
│  ├── last.ml
│  └── last_two.ml
├── ocaml_exercises.opam
└── test
   ├── dune
   ├── last_tests.ml
   └── last_two_tests.ml
```

So here's where my problem arises, I can't for the life of me work out how to correctly reference the functions in `/lib/last[_two].ml` from `test/last[_two]_tests.ml`.

My dune files look like:

```
// bin/dune
(executable
 (public_name ocaml_exercises)
 (name main)
 (modules Main)
 (libraries Ocaml_exercises))

//lib/dune
(library
 (name ocaml_exercises)
 (public_name ocaml_exercises)
 (modules Last Last_two))

//test/dune
(test
 (name ocaml_exercises)
 (libraries ocaml_exercises)
 (modules Last_tests Last_two_tests))
```

However, when I try to run `dune test`, I get:

> File "bin/dune", line 4, characters 10-25: 4 |  (modules
> ocaml_exercises)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error: Module Ocaml_exercises doesn't exist. File "test/dune", line 2, characters 7-22: 2 |  (name
> ocaml_exercises)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error: The name "Ocaml_exercises" is not listed in the (modules) field of this stanza.

I'm somewhat confused here, my understanding was that:

- `Modules` is essentially an include-list of the files it should include in library compilation
- `public_name` is how you would refer to that library externally
- `libraries` is a list of libraries you want to link to

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Why do you have the name capitalized in `libraries` but not elsewhere. Don't know about the error message, but I would at least think names are case-sensitive, and that seems suspect.

Comment: I was under the impression that that's what the compiler did to file-names to generate module names from them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the module-name is capitalised. No you don't capitalise a library (which could contain several modules).

So... you probably want in `test/dune` something like:

```
(libraries alcotest lib)
```

And then in your test files you refer to `Lib.Last` for the module.